# SQL - Clarification - ISNULL()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following logic in a stored procedure.

What is being accomplished here?

***If color is null, replace with ' '***

```
IF ISNULL(@color, '') <> '' 
BEGIN
END
```

Comment: It's `If @color is not NULL and @color is not '' then....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is same as:

```
IF (@color IS NOT NULL AND @color <> '') 
   THEN ...
```

One more thing,  try to use `COALESCE` function instead of `ISNULL`,  because first is proposed by SQL Standard. Syntax is pretty same:

```
IF COALESCE(@color, '') <> '' 
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Comment: which ultimately is the same as `IF @color <> ''`

Answer (score 2):

When `@color is NULL` it is replaced with `''`.

So when `@color` has a value (`NOT NULL OR''`) the `BEGIN .. END` will be executed.

Comment: If `@color` has a value '' then `BEGIN ... END` block will not be executed

Comment: My mistake, I did not make full attention at content in braces. Excuse me

Comment: No problem it happens :)

Comment: I did not see that in not `NULL` only NULL word is highlighted, I meant that both words are highlighted which can be another context :)